# Join 3 tables with codeigniter and display it

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I want to create a join database. in the 'relation' table will show 'disease' which can add many 'symptoms'. How should I do it?

Here is my database:

disease : id_disease, name, details
symptoms : id_symptoms, name, details
relation : id_relation, id_disease, id_symptoms

and here is my model

```
function get_allrelation() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('relation');
    $this->db->join('disease','disease.id_disease = relastion.id_disease','left');
    $this->db->join('symptoms','symptoms.id_symptoms= relation.id_symptoms','left');

    $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller below is a example only in the select `$this->db->select('relation.*, disease.*, symptoms.*');`

Oon the controller you can pass the data to the view the create a foreach loop in the view.

```
<?php

class Somecontroller extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {

        $data['allrelation'] = $this->allrelation();


        $this->load->view('example', $data);

    }

    function get_allrelation() {
        $this->db->select('relation.*, disease.*, symptoms.*');
        $this->db->from('relation');
        $this->db->join('disease','disease.id_disease = relastion.id_disease','left');
        $this->db->join('symptoms','symptoms.id_symptoms = relation.id_symptoms','left');

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        }

        return false
    }

}
```

Comment: `relation.*, disease.*, symptoms.*` using `*` in the Select may lead to ambigious column error in the Future. So it is better to specify the column name instead of `*`

Answer (score 1):

You had a typo: instead of relation you had relastion.id_disease.

Code below should work

```
function get_allrelation() {
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('relation');
  $this->db->join('disease','disease.id_disease = relation.id_disease','left');
  $this->db->join('symptoms','symptoms.id_symptoms= relation.id_symptoms','left');

  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: I know it works. but I failed to add the disease data. the data is empty

Comment: whats the data that you have in the tables?

Also could be a chance that the symptoms is left joined on disease instead of on symptoms .

Comment: I have tried it from user4419336 and it works. and beforehand there were little errors on the controllers. Thank you for the help :)